# Pandas Fill column with date

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to fill a DataFrame column(entire column) in with a static date but which has to be a variable.  I am able to fill in numbers using numpy, but I am unable to fill in a date for a column:

```
currdate = ['3/31/2018'] #this is what I need filled in
missing = ['GREEN', 'YELLOW', 'RED', 'BLUE', 'PINK']
```

Section 1:

```
A = ({'PERIOD DT':                     pd.to_datetime(currdate),
           'TEAM':                              missing,
           'REGION':                            ['NA'],
           'SECTOR':                            ['OTHER'],
           'REVENUE':                           [0]})
```

Can anyone explain why the above code does not fill down in each respective column?  For each column with the exception of 'TEAM', the values only fill in the first row of data within the DataFrame.

```
DF = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(A, orient='index')
DF= DF.transpose()
```

Section 2:

```
zeroVal = [0]
n = len(DF)
DF['SECTOR'] = 'OTHER'
DF['REGION'] = 'NA'
DF.loc[:,'REVENUE'] = np.zeros(n)
```

I tried using the below to fill in the 'currdate' I am using in the 'PERIOD DT' column, but I am unable to get it to work:

```
DF['PERIOD DT'] = pd.to_datetime(currdate)
```

Without telling each column what to do in section 2, I get the following output:
I would like all of the values in the columns to be the same filled down each column with the exception of the TEAM that i fill in using a variable referencing a list

```
    PERIOD DT    TEAM    REGION    SECTOR    REVENUE
0   2018-03-31   GREEN   NA        OTHER     0.00
1       NONE     YELLOW  NONE      NONE      NONE
2       NONE     RED     NONE      NONE      NONE
3       NONE     BLUE    NONE      NONE      NONE
4       NONE     PINK    NONE      NONE      NONE
```

My intended output:

```
    PERIOD DT    TEAM    REGION    SECTOR    REVENUE
0   2018-03-31   GREEN   NA        OTHER     0.00
1   2018-03-31   YELLOW  NA        OTHER     0.00
2   2018-03-31   RED     NA        OTHER     0.00
3   2018-03-31   BLUE    NA        OTHER     0.00
4   2018-03-31   PINK    NA        OTHER     0.00
```

Questions: 1, why can't i get the variable/DF 'A' to fill down each column based on the information i supplied and 
2 how do i manually fill in the date (via a variable) down the column 'PERIOD DT'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `missing` list has 5 elements while other lists have only 1. All the lists in the dict that you pass for dataframes should have same number of elements. Consider below approach.

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'PERIOD DT': list(pd.to_datetime(currdate)) * len(missing),
           'TEAM': missing,
           'REGION': ['NA']* len(missing),
           'SECTOR': ['OTHER'] * len(missing),
           'REVENUE': [0] * len(missing)
})
```

Output:

```
PERIOD DT   TEAM    REGION  SECTOR  REVENUE
0   3/31/2018   GREEN   NA  OTHER   0
1   3/31/2018   YELLOW  NA  OTHER   0
2   3/31/2018   RED NA  OTHER   0
3   3/31/2018   BLUE    NA  OTHER   0
4   3/31/2018   PINK    NA  OTHER   0
```

Comment: thank you for your help, this works great with the exception of the first line: 'PERIOD DT' - i am getting the following error: 'TypeError: 'list' object is not callable' - am i missing something in the code? i am still using the lines:

Comment: DF = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(A, orient='index')
DF= DF.transpose()

Comment: also, is there another way to just hardcode the date in the dataframe similar to 'DF['column'] = 'date'?

Comment: ok, it looks like if i remove the pd.to_datetime section and only use the variable, it works!  thanks again for your help!